# Why does Angular Material2 use ViewEncapsulation.None instead of Emulated or Native?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-material2

In the Material2 project every component uses ViewEncapsulation.None. (e.g. the [MdButton](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/components/button/button.ts#L30))

Recently the encapsulation has just been changed to None for [md-toolbar](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/676).

Why is that so? Isn't the possibility to encapsulate the CSS one of the biggest advantages of creating such a framework with Angular2.

Polymer Components seem to use this feature. Why doesn't Material2?

Answer (score 2):

A while ago `/deep/` and `>>>` were implemented for `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` therefore it should be easy to style the same as with `ViewEncapsulation.None`.

The only reason I can think of is that SASS (or whatever preprocessor they use) doesn't support these CSS combinators because they are deprecated since almost a year in Chrome and were never implemented in other browsers.

Comment: What I'm aiming at is the more opposite: IMHO The /deep/ or  >>> selector shouldn't be needed at all. Everything could be included in the component styles whithout any dependencies on global styles. But I'm wondering why Material doesn't do it that way.

Comment: I assume this is to support themeing and customizing the default styles (applied to components) from the outside.

Comment: Polymer has CSS variables and mixins that work across component boundaries. Angular2 doesn't have anything compareable yet.

Comment: Even using `ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom` you can still `@import 'shared-theme.scss'` across each component if you want the effect of working across component boundaries.  So I still fail to see the point of choosing `ViewEncapsulation.None` in Angular Material.

Comment: After more thought I came to one conclusion that makes sense.  Angular may have allowed `ViewEncapsulation.None` for the sake of the user base.  Implementors can provide their own class, `.mat-radio-button` for example, in their own projects to over-ride Angular's themes.  In Angular's Materials case because they have so many users they probably chose to simply give people the option to create their own disasters.  This decision would require the library maintainer (Ang. Mat) to be more precise in their own coding.  Which I'm sure they are fully capable.

Comment: Proprietary corporate projects that control their own component libraries should likely stick to the ShadowDom or Emulated.  Maintaining the level of precision and quality across many teams in a corporation would likely prove to be a bigger challenge than most companies can manage.